# Keras, How to get the output of each layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have trained a binary classification model with CNN, and here is my code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1],
                        border_mode='valid',
                        input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
# (16, 16, 32)
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters*2, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters*2, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
# (8, 8, 64) = (2048)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2))  # define a binary classification problem
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

And here, I wanna get the output of each layer just like TensorFlow, how can I do that?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You can easily get the outputs of any layer by using: `model.layers[index].output`

For all layers use this:

```
from keras import backend as K

inp = model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functors = [K.function([inp, K.learning_phase()], [out]) for out in outputs]    # evaluation functions

# Testing
test = np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]
layer_outs = [func([test, 1.]) for func in functors]
print layer_outs
```

Note: To simulate Dropout use `learning_phase` as `1.` in `layer_outs` otherwise use `0.`

**Edit:** (based on comments)

`K.function` creates theano/tensorflow tensor functions which is later used to get the output from the symbolic graph given the input.

Now `K.learning_phase()` is required as an input as many Keras layers like Dropout/Batchnomalization depend on it to change behavior during training and test time.

So if you remove the dropout layer in your code you can simply use:

```
from keras import backend as K

inp = model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functors = [K.function([inp], [out]) for out in outputs]    # evaluation functions

# Testing
test = np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]
layer_outs = [func([test]) for func in functors]
print layer_outs
```

**Edit 2: More optimized**

I just realized that the previous answer is not that optimized as for each function evaluation the data will be transferred CPU->GPU memory and also the tensor calculations needs to be done for the lower layers over-n-over.

Instead this is a much better way as you don't need multiple functions but a single function giving you the list of all outputs:

```
from keras import backend as K

inp = model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functor = K.function([inp, K.learning_phase()], outputs )   # evaluation function

# Testing
test = np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]
layer_outs = functor([test, 1.])
print layer_outs
```

Comment: sir, your answer is good, what `K.function([inp]+ [K.learning_phase()], [out])` mean in your code?

Comment: Excellent answer, `np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]` can also be written as `np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,:]`

Comment: What is K.function ? how do it passed to GPU ( MPI ?) ? what is there behind the scene ? How it is talks with CUDA  ? where is the source code ?

Comment: @indraforyou How do you explain that this method is much more slower then just calling model.predict ? As I understand both of them should make all the calculations on the GPU...I did tested and model.predict is much more faster in my case , any explanation please ? Thanks.

Comment: @StavBodik Model builds the predict function using `K.function` [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1007-L1011), and predict uses it in the predict loop [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1800-L1803). Predict loops over the batch size (if not set it defaults to 32) but thats to mitigate constraints on GPU memory. So i am not sure why you are observing `model.predict` is faster.

Comment: Thanks , this sounds to me like some bug in my code using the time.time() function in python...will check this out.

Comment: It gives this error to me `ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)`. Here my tensor obj is `Tensor("data:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)`

Comment: Am getting this: InvalidArgumentError: S_input_39:0 is both fed and fetched. ... anyone with ideas?

Comment: Does anyone encounter this issue?  `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`

Comment: Any possibility to get the delta values in each cells in each layer? eg: Delta out, delta state, delta a, delta f, delta i ,delta o.

Comment: Error when running `test = np.random.random(model.input.shape)[np.newaxis,:]` error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`... i think it's because my shape is `[None, 4]` not `[4,]`?

Comment: This only allows you to print the output of a single layer given a single input, but this does not allow you to see the output a layer that is preceded by another layer (or `N` other layers), given some input.

Comment: Error: ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: 0 (missing previous layer metadata). Simple model: inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=None)(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x). tf version 2.5.0. Only first method works.

Answer (score 212):

From https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer

One simple way is to create a new Model that will output the layers that you are interested in:

```
from keras.models import Model

model = ...  # include here your original model

layer_name = 'my_layer'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

Alternatively, you can build a Keras function that will return the output of a certain layer given a certain input, for example:

```
from keras import backend as K

# with a Sequential model
get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  [model.layers[3].output])
layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([x])[0]
```

Comment: if I could i'd give you two ^, This way is just sooooo much more convenient when you have a bunch of inputs.

Comment: It's pretty clear from your code above but just to double check my understanding: after creating a model from an existing model(assuming it's already trained), there is no need to call set_weights on the new model. Is that correct?

Comment: what is the difference between `layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X, 0])[0]` and `layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X, 1])[0]` The docs mention train mode and test mode

Comment: sorry, can you explain me what does this model do exactly? Do you have to train it as well? I cannot imagine any diagram to it. You add the input layer of another model, then add a random intermediary layer of that other model as output, and feed inputs to it? Why do this instead of feeding the original model and get direct access to any intermediary layer it in? Why create this extra strange model? And won't it affect the output? won't it try to learn or require training, or the layer brings its own weights pre trained from the original model?

Comment: This answer works well. Thanks for providing this answer

Answer (score 33):

Based on all the good answers of this thread, I wrote a library to fetch the output of each layer. It abstracts all the complexity and has been designed to be as user-friendly as possible:

https://github.com/philipperemy/keract

It handles almost all the edge cases.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 15):

Following looks very simple to me:

```
model.layers[idx].output
```

Above is a tensor object, so you can modify it using operations that can be applied to a tensor object.

For example, to get the shape `model.layers[idx].output.get_shape()`

`idx` is the index of the layer and you can find it from `model.summary()`

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? Why isn't this upvoted as the top answer?

Comment: It returns a tensor object, not a dataframe. tf objects are weird to work with.

Comment: The poster said they want to get the output of each layer. Given some data, how can you get the layer output from `model.layers[idx].output`?

Answer (score 12):

This answer is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59557567/2585501

To print the output of a single layer:

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
layerIndex = 1
func = K.function([model.get_layer(index=0).input], model.get_layer(index=layerIndex).output)
layerOutput = func([input_data])  # input_data is a numpy array
print(layerOutput)
```

To print output of every layer:

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
for layerIndex, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    func = K.function([model.get_layer(index=0).input], layer.output)
    layerOutput = func([input_data])  # input_data is a numpy array
    print(layerOutput)
```

Comment: I used your code-lines after fit and got printed gradient descend weights ... if my use was correct & if matrices printed, that I've got, are gradients (here weights) ? Anyway, thank you! ..

Comment: Does input data refer to the test data I use to get the model's predictions? Like I used `pred =  my_model.predict(X)` for the prediction. Should I use this `X` instead of input_data?

Answer (score 9):

Previous solutions were not working for me. I handled this issue as shown below.

```
layer_outputs = []
for i in range(1, len(model.layers)):
    tmp_model = Model(model.layers[0].input, model.layers[i].output)
    tmp_output = tmp_model.predict(img)[0]
    layer_outputs.append(tmp_output)
```

Comment: What is "Model" here?

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for ! +1

Answer (score 8):

I wrote this function for myself (in Jupyter) and it was inspired by [indraforyou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2217210/indraforyou)'s answer. It will plot all the layer outputs automatically. Your images must have a (x, y, 1) shape where 1 stands for 1 channel. You just call plot_layer_outputs(...) to plot.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import backend as K

def get_layer_outputs():
    test_image = YOUR IMAGE GOES HERE!!!
    outputs    = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
    comp_graph = [K.function([model.input]+ [K.learning_phase()], [output]) for output in outputs]  # evaluation functions

    # Testing
    layer_outputs_list = [op([test_image, 1.]) for op in comp_graph]
    layer_outputs = []

    for layer_output in layer_outputs_list:
        print(layer_output[0][0].shape, end='\n-------------------\n')
        layer_outputs.append(layer_output[0][0])

    return layer_outputs

def plot_layer_outputs(layer_number):    
    layer_outputs = get_layer_outputs()

    x_max = layer_outputs[layer_number].shape[0]
    y_max = layer_outputs[layer_number].shape[1]
    n     = layer_outputs[layer_number].shape[2]

    L = []
    for i in range(n):
        L.append(np.zeros((x_max, y_max)))

    for i in range(n):
        for x in range(x_max):
            for y in range(y_max):
                L[i][x][y] = layer_outputs[layer_number][x][y][i]


    for img in L:
        plt.figure()
        plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: What if the model has several inputs? How to you specify the inputs?

Comment: In this line: layer_outputs_list = [op([test_image, 1.]). Does 1. need to be 0? It seems 1 stands for training and 0 stands for testing? Isn't is?

Comment: This is not working for me. I have used a color image and it is giving me error : InvalidArgumentError: input_2:0 is both fed and fetched.

Answer (score 7):

From: https://github.com/philipperemy/keras-visualize-activations/blob/master/read_activations.py

```
import keras.backend as K

def get_activations(model, model_inputs, print_shape_only=False, layer_name=None):
    print('----- activations -----')
    activations = []
    inp = model.input

    model_multi_inputs_cond = True
    if not isinstance(inp, list):
        # only one input! let's wrap it in a list.
        inp = [inp]
        model_multi_inputs_cond = False

    outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers if
               layer.name == layer_name or layer_name is None]  # all layer outputs

    funcs = [K.function(inp + [K.learning_phase()], [out]) for out in outputs]  # evaluation functions

    if model_multi_inputs_cond:
        list_inputs = []
        list_inputs.extend(model_inputs)
        list_inputs.append(0.)
    else:
        list_inputs = [model_inputs, 0.]

    # Learning phase. 0 = Test mode (no dropout or batch normalization)
    # layer_outputs = [func([model_inputs, 0.])[0] for func in funcs]
    layer_outputs = [func(list_inputs)[0] for func in funcs]
    for layer_activations in layer_outputs:
        activations.append(layer_activations)
        if print_shape_only:
            print(layer_activations.shape)
        else:
            print(layer_activations)
    return activations
```

Comment: Link is deprecated.

Comment: It'd be great if you could explain your code and provide more information

Answer (score 6):

Wanted to add this as a comment (but don't have high enough rep.) to @indraforyou's answer to correct for the issue mentioned in @mathtick's comment. To avoid the `InvalidArgumentError: input_X:Y is both fed and fetched.` exception, simply replace the line `outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]` with `outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers][1:]`, i.e.

adapting indraforyou's minimal working example:

```
from keras import backend as K 
inp = model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers][1:]        # all layer outputs except first (input) layer
functor = K.function([inp, K.learning_phase()], outputs )   # evaluation function

# Testing
test = np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]
layer_outs = functor([test, 1.])
print layer_outs
```

p.s. my attempts trying things such as `outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[1:]]` did not work.

Comment: that is not exactly correct. This is only if input layer is the first defined.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me and I just want to check I understand why, based on Mpizos' comment: my model is just 3 layers (word embeddings - BiLSTM - CRF), so I guess I had to exclude layer[0] since it's just embeddings and shouldn't have an activation, right?

Comment: @MpizosDimitris yes that is correct, but in the example provided by @indraforyou (which I was amending), this was the case. @KMunro if I'm understanding correctly, then the reason you don't care about your output of the first layer is because it is simply the output of the word embedding which is just the word embedding itself in tensor form (which is just the input to the "network" part of your `keras` model). Your word embeddings layer is equivalent to the input layer in the example provided here.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have:

1- Keras pre-trained `model`.

2- Input `x` as image or set of images. The resolution of image should be compatible with dimension of the input layer. For example **80*80*3** for 3-channels (RGB) image.

3- The name of the output `layer` to get the activation. For example, "flatten_2" layer. This should be include in the `layer_names` variable, represents name of layers of the given `model`.

4- `batch_size` is an optional argument.

Then you can easily use `get_activation` function to get the activation of the output `layer` for a given input `x` and pre-trained `model`:

```
import six
import numpy as np
import keras.backend as k
from numpy import float32
def get_activations(x, model, layer, batch_size=128):
"""
Return the output of the specified layer for input `x`. `layer` is specified by layer index (between 0 and
`nb_layers - 1`) or by name. The number of layers can be determined by counting the results returned by
calling `layer_names`.
:param x: Input for computing the activations.
:type x: `np.ndarray`. Example: x.shape = (80, 80, 3)
:param model: pre-trained Keras model. Including weights.
:type model: keras.engine.sequential.Sequential. Example: model.input_shape = (None, 80, 80, 3)
:param layer: Layer for computing the activations
:type layer: `int` or `str`. Example: layer = 'flatten_2'
:param batch_size: Size of batches.
:type batch_size: `int`
:return: The output of `layer`, where the first dimension is the batch size corresponding to `x`.
:rtype: `np.ndarray`. Example: activations.shape = (1, 2000)
"""

    layer_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]
    if isinstance(layer, six.string_types):
        if layer not in layer_names:
            raise ValueError('Layer name %s is not part of the graph.' % layer)
        layer_name = layer
    elif isinstance(layer, int):
        if layer < 0 or layer >= len(layer_names):
            raise ValueError('Layer index %d is outside of range (0 to %d included).'
                             % (layer, len(layer_names) - 1))
        layer_name = layer_names[layer]
    else:
        raise TypeError('Layer must be of type `str` or `int`.')

    layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output
    layer_input = model.input
    output_func = k.function([layer_input], [layer_output])

    # Apply preprocessing
    if x.shape == k.int_shape(model.input)[1:]:
        x_preproc = np.expand_dims(x, 0)
    else:
        x_preproc = x
    assert len(x_preproc.shape) == 4

    # Determine shape of expected output and prepare array
    output_shape = output_func([x_preproc[0][None, ...]])[0].shape
    activations = np.zeros((x_preproc.shape[0],) + output_shape[1:], dtype=float32)

    # Get activations with batching
    for batch_index in range(int(np.ceil(x_preproc.shape[0] / float(batch_size)))):
        begin, end = batch_index * batch_size, min((batch_index + 1) * batch_size, x_preproc.shape[0])
        activations[begin:end] = output_func([x_preproc[begin:end]])[0]

    return activations
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you have one of the following cases:

- error: `InvalidArgumentError: input_X:Y is both fed and fetched`
- case of multiple inputs

You need to do the following changes:

- add filter out for input layers in `outputs` variable
- minnor change on `functors` loop

Minimum example:

```
from keras.engine.input_layer import InputLayer
inp = model.input
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers if not isinstance(layer, InputLayer)]
functors = [K.function(inp + [K.learning_phase()], [x]) for x in outputs]
layer_outputs = [fun([x1, x2, xn, 1]) for fun in functors]
```

Comment: What is meant by `[x1, x2, xn, 1]`? My x1 is not defined and I would like to understand what you are defining there.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax `x1` and `x2` are the inputs of the model. As stated thats incase you got 2 inputs on your model.

Answer (score 0):

Well, other answers are very complete, but there is a very basic way to "see", not to "get" the shapes.

Just do a `model.summary()`. It will print all layers and their output shapes. "None" values will indicate variable dimensions, and the first dimension will be the batch size.

Comment: This is about the output of the layer (given inputs to the base layer) not the layer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, output size can be calculated as

`[(W−K+2P)/S]+1`

where

```
W is the input volume - in your case you have not given us this
K is the Kernel size - in your case 2 == "filter" 
P is the padding - in your case 2
S is the stride - in your case 3
```

Another, prettier formulation:

[image: The prettied-up equation]