# Viewing layer activations with Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

In NVIDIA's paper "[End to End Learning for Self-Driving Cars](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07316)" there's an illustration showing the activation of first-layer feature maps:

[image: Image from End to End Learning for Self-Driving Cars]

I'm trying to recreate this with the [Comma AI model](https://github.com/commaai/research), but the only visualisation tools I've found are [Keras' instructions for gradient ascent and descent](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html), rather than simply viewing activations. what should I be looking for?

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT

I tried implementing the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer/41712013#41712013) using the below code:

```
from keras import backend as K
import json
from keras.models import model_from_json

with open('outputs/steering_model/steering_angle.json', 'r') as jfile:
    z = json.load(jfile)
    model = model_from_json(z)
print("Loaded model")
model.load_weights('outputs/steering_model/steering_angle.keras')
print("Loaded weights")

img_width = 320
img_height = 160

outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functors = [K.function([inp]+ [K.learning_phase()], [out]) for out in outputs]  # evaluation functions

# Testing
test = np.random.random((1, 3, img_width, img_height))
layer_outs = [func([test, 1.]) for func in functors]
print layer_outs
```

This give the following output error:

```
Using Theano backend.
Loaded model
Loaded weights
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vis-layers.py", line 22, in <module>
    layer_outs = [func([test, 1.]) for func in functors]
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 959, in __call__
    return self.function(*inputs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 871, in __call__
    storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 314, in raise_with_op
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 859, in __call__
    outputs = self.fn()
ValueError: Shape mismatch: x has 49152 cols (and 1 rows) but y has 12800 rows (and 512 cols)
Apply node that caused the error: Dot22(Elemwise{Composite{Switch(GT(i0, i1), i0, expm1(i0))}}[(0, 0)].0, dense_1_W)
Toposort index: 50
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 49152), (12800, 512)]
Inputs strides: [(196608, 4), (2048, 4)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Elemwise{Add}[(0, 0)](Dot22.0, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}.0)]]
```

I thought this might be a problem with th vs tf dimensions, so tried changing the test input to:

```
test = np.random.random((1, img_height, img_width, 3))
```

which gave the following error:

```
Using Theano backend.
Loaded model
Loaded weights
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vis-layers.py", line 22, in <module>
    layer_outs = [func([test, 1.]) for func in functors]
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 959, in __call__
    return self.function(*inputs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 871, in __call__
    storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 314, in raise_with_op
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 859, in __call__
    outputs = self.fn()
ValueError: CorrMM images and kernel must have the same stack size

Apply node that caused the error: CorrMM{half, (4, 4)}(Elemwise{Composite{(i0 + (i1 * i2))}}.0, Subtensor{::, ::, ::int64, ::int64}.0)
Toposort index: 9
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, 4D), TensorType(float32, 4D)]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 320, 160, 3), (16, 3, 8, 8)]
Inputs strides: [(2250000, 6000, 12, 4), (768, 256, -32, -4)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Subtensor{int64:int64:int8, int64:int64:int8, int64:int64:int8, int64:int64:int8}(CorrMM{half, (4, 4)}.0, ScalarFromTensor.0, ScalarFromTensor.0, Constant{1}, Constant{0}, Constant{16}, Constant{1}, ScalarFromTensor.0, ScalarFromTensor.0, Constant{1}, ScalarFromTensor.0, ScalarFromTensor.0, Constant{1})]]

Backtrace when the node is created(use Theano flag traceback.limit=N to make it longer):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/layer_utils.py", line 43, in layer_from_config
    return layer_class.from_config(config['config'])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 1091, in from_config
    model.add(layer)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 332, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 572, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 635, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 166, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 475, in call
    filter_shape=self.W_shape)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1508, in conv2d
    filter_shape=filter_shape)
```

EDIT: Output of model.summary()

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
lambda_1 (Lambda)                (None, 3, 160, 320)   0           lambda_input_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)  (None, 16, 40, 80)    3088        lambda_1[0][0]                   
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
elu_1 (ELU)                      (None, 16, 40, 80)    0           convolution2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_2 (Convolution2D)  (None, 32, 20, 40)    12832       elu_1[0][0]                      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
elu_2 (ELU)                      (None, 32, 20, 40)    0           convolution2d_2[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_3 (Convolution2D)  (None, 64, 10, 20)    51264       elu_2[0][0]                      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)              (None, 12800)         0           convolution2d_3[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)              (None, 12800)         0           flatten_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
elu_3 (ELU)                      (None, 12800)         0           dropout_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 512)           6554112     elu_3[0][0]                      
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)              (None, 512)           0           dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
elu_4 (ELU)                      (None, 512)           0           dropout_2[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 1)             513         elu_4[0][0]                      
====================================================================================================
Total params: 6,621,809
Trainable params: 6,621,809
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

EDIT: DEBUGGING WITH SINGLE LAYER

In order to debug the issue with input shapes, I rewrote the script for a single layer:

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import json
from keras.models import model_from_json

with open('outputs/steering_model/steering_angle.json', 'r') as jfile:
    z = json.load(jfile)
    model = model_from_json(z)
print("Loaded model")
model.load_weights('outputs/steering_model/steering_angle.keras')
print("Loaded weights")

layer_name = 'lambda_1'

img_width = 160
img_height = 320

inp = model.input
layer_idx = [idx for idx, layer in enumerate(model.layers) if layer.name == layer_name][0]
output = model.layers[layer_idx].output
functor = K.function([inp]+ [K.learning_phase()], output)  # evaluation function

# Testing
test = np.random.random((1, img_height, img_width, 3))
layer_out = functor([test, 1.])
print layer_out
```

The output from this is as follows:

```
Using Theano backend.
Loaded model
Loaded weights
[[[[-0.99223709 -0.99468529 -0.99318016]
   [-0.99725926 -0.9924705  -0.9994905 ]
   [-0.99380279 -0.99291307 -0.99927235]
   ..., 
   [-0.99361622 -0.99258155 -0.99954134]
   [-0.99748689 -0.99217939 -0.99918425]
   [-0.99475586 -0.99366009 -0.992827  ]]

  [[-0.99330682 -0.99756712 -0.99795902]
   [-0.99421203 -0.99240923 -0.99438184]
   [-0.99222761 -0.99425066 -0.99886942]
   ..., 
   [-0.99329156 -0.99460274 -0.99994165]
   [-0.99763876 -0.99870259 -0.9998613 ]
   [-0.99962425 -0.99702215 -0.9943046 ]]

  [[-0.99947125 -0.99577188 -0.99294066]
   [-0.99582225 -0.99568367 -0.99345332]
   [-0.99823713 -0.99376178 -0.99432898]
   ..., 
   [-0.99828976 -0.99264622 -0.99669623]
   [-0.99485278 -0.99353015 -0.99411404]
   [-0.99832171 -0.99390954 -0.99620205]]

  ..., 
  [[-0.9980613  -0.99474132 -0.99680966]
   [-0.99378282 -0.99288809 -0.99248403]
   [-0.99375945 -0.9966079  -0.99440354]
   ..., 
   [-0.99634677 -0.99931824 -0.99611002]
   [-0.99781156 -0.99990571 -0.99249381]
   [-0.9996115  -0.99991143 -0.99486816]]

  [[-0.99839222 -0.99690026 -0.99410695]
   [-0.99551272 -0.99262673 -0.99934679]
   [-0.99432331 -0.99822938 -0.99294668]
   ..., 
   [-0.99515969 -0.99867356 -0.9926796 ]
   [-0.99478716 -0.99883151 -0.99760127]
   [-0.9982425  -0.99547088 -0.99658638]]

  [[-0.99240851 -0.99792403 -0.99360847]
   [-0.99226022 -0.99546915 -0.99411654]
   [-0.99558711 -0.9960795  -0.9993062 ]
   ..., 
   [-0.99745959 -0.99276334 -0.99800634]
   [-0.99249429 -0.99748743 -0.99576926]
   [-0.99531293 -0.99618822 -0.99997312]]]]
```

However, attempting the same on the first convolutional layer (convolution2d_1) with an 80x40 image returns the same error:

```
ValueError: CorrMM images and kernel must have the same stack size

Apply node that caused the error: CorrMM{half, (4, 4)}(Elemwise{Composite{(i0 + (i1 * i2))}}.0, Subtensor{::, ::, ::int64, ::int64}.0)
Toposort index: 9
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, 4D), TensorType(float32, 4D)]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 40, 80, 3), (16, 3, 8, 8)]
Inputs strides: [(38400, 960, 12, 4), (768, 256, -32, -4)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Subtensor{int64:int64:int8, int64:int64:int8, int64:int64:int8, int64:int64:int8}(CorrMM{half, (4, 4)}.0, ScalarFromTensor.0, ScalarFromTensor.0, Constant{1}, Constant{0}, Constant{16}, Constant{1}, ScalarFromTensor.0, ScalarFromTensor.0, Constant{1}, ScalarFromTensor.0, ScalarFromTensor.0, Constant{1})]]
```

EDIT: OUTPUT LAYER DATA AS IMAGE

The following code replaces the random image with a loaded one, and takes the layer output and saves it as an image:

```
input_img_data = imread(impath+'.png').astype(np.float32)
# change image to 4d theano array
test = np.expand_dims(input_img_data,axis=0)
print test.shape
layer_out = functor([test, 1.])
img = Image.fromarray(layer_out[0,:,:,:], 'RGB')
img.save('activ_%s_%s.png' % (layer_name,impath))
print("Created Image")
```

Comment: You can get the output of any keras layer which is nothing but activation of the layer. For more check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer/41712013#41712013. You can then visualize the output however you want

Comment: @indraforyou thanks very much - I tried to implement your code, but got stuck - any idea what I am doing wrong? (code in edit above)

Comment: Can to post the `model.summary()`

Comment: @indraforyou Added the model.summary()

Comment: I have to change the input size for each layer?

Comment: Not sure. I would guess the input shape is different from the Lambda layer output shape. Also instead of taking the output from each layer just take one layer and try to get the output of that layer. That will make debugging easier.

Comment: I rewrote the code to get outputs from single layer. This is successful on the Lambda layer for a 320x160 image, but doesn't work on the next layer with either 320x160 or 80x40, so not sure I'm any closer.

Comment: I'm also unsure how to visualise this output in a manner similar to the example in the NVIDIA paper.

Comment: I figured out how to export this layer as an image - see edit - but I'm no closer to visualising other layers than the Lambda. Any ideas?

Comment: Great you figured out the problem. For visualization you can stitch all the images together into a single image. For reference you can check: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py#L83-L97

Comment: @indrafor you - thanks for all your help

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code that does what I want it to do, still rough and in need of tidying up:

```
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import Image
from scipy.misc import imread
from scipy.misc import imsave
import numpy as np
import json
from keras.models import model_from_json

with open('outputs/steering_model/steering_angle.json', 'r') as jfile:
    z = json.load(jfile)
    model = model_from_json(z)
print("Loaded model")
model.load_weights('outputs/steering_model/steering_angle.keras')
print("Loaded weights")

layer_name = 'lambda_1'
#layer_name = 'convolution2d_1'
#layer_name = 'elu_1'
#layer_name = 'convolution2d_2'

impaths = ['track','road','mway']

img_width = 500
img_height = 375

inp = model.input
layer_idx = [idx for idx, layer in enumerate(model.layers) if layer.name == layer_name][0]
output = model.layers[layer_idx].output
functor = K.function([inp]+ [K.learning_phase()], output)  # evaluation function

for impath in impaths:
    input_img_data = imread('testimages/'+impath+'.png').astype(np.float32)
    input_img_data = np.rollaxis(input_img_data,2,0)   # change to (channels,h,w)
    test = np.expand_dims(input_img_data,axis=0)       # change to (dims,channels,h,w)

    print("Test Shape: %s" % (test.shape,))            # check shape

    layer_out = functor([test, 1.])
    print ("Output Shape: %s" % (layer_out.shape,))    # check output shape

    # save multiple greyscale images
    layer_out = np.rollaxis(layer_out,0,4)
    print ("Output Image Shape: %s" % (layer_out.shape,))    # check output shape    
    count = 1
    for x in layer_out:
        x = np.rollaxis(x,2,0)
        print ("Final Image Shape: %s" % (x.shape,))    # check output shape
        imsave('activationimages/activ_%s_%s_%d.png' % (layer_name,impath,count),x[0,:,:])
        count = count + 1
```

The main issue was wrangling the shapes of the various input and output layers - hence all the print commands in the above code, for debugging.

A second confusion was that I was interpreting an array shape of (3,w,h) as a single RGB (3-channel) image, rather than one greyscale image.

The version above tests an array of images at a time (hardcoded image path). The lambda_1 level outputs a single RGB image per test image, convolution2d_1 and elu_1 output sixteen smaller (25%) greyscale images - one for each filter. And, I hope, so on.

I will add a Github link to a tidied gist with image stitching when I've done this. I've learned a lot.