# Accessing output values of inner layers

Tags: python, keras

I have a Keras neural network shown in the attached picture

[image: Keras model].

I train this network with certain sequences of the form `#abcd$`, plus the other inputs which stay fixed for the entire sequence.

The prediction starts with passing to the network the first symbol `#` (plus the other inputs), decoding its output into the vector `v`, then passing `v` as the new input (till the network generates the symbol `$`).

For each prediction (on the test set), I need to access the output values of the hidden layers, in particular of the layer `inner_concat` (or the two dense layers that are concatenated in `inner_concat`).

From the documentation and from the debugger (looking into the Keras model) I cannot understand how I can access those values after a `model.predict`.

Is there anyone who can help me or provide a pointer to the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the output of a layer simply by `model.layers[idx].output`. For a more detailed answer see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to get the value of the node `net` (how it was called once upon a time), i.e. output = lambda net. activation(net).

Furtuermore, is there any mapping between layer names and layer indexes? Do I need to print the summary of the network and count the layers?

Comment: You can get a layer by name via `model.get_layer(name='layername')`

Comment: It is not that easy as `.output`. I have read the thread you linked, but could not understand how to specify the various inputs my network has. Do you have an idea?