# How to get the neuronal activations and their probabilities from Softmax in Keras

Tags: keras, prediction

I noticed that with in keras `predict_proba` and `predict` I get the same result, which is a list of the class probabilities. But how can I get the neural activations from the Softmax function in keras? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras retrieve value of node before activation function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492318/keras-retrieve-value-of-node-before-activation-function)

Comment: What I would like to have are the values of the node output before the Softmax activation.