# Use Glove vectors without Embedding layers in LSTM

Tags: python, keras, nlp, word-embedding, glove

I want to use the Glove vectors in Language Modeling. But the problem is if I use Embedding layer in the model, I can't predict the output vector and match the word. What I mean here is, I want to give the glove vector representation for my sentences as the Input. and get them out from the Lstm layer and get the vectors and match it with Glove vectors I want to use the glove vectors without embedding layer.  can someone propose a method to do it? I am using the keras and python3

What I want is to use the embedding layer as one model1 and return the output vector and give it to another LSTM model2 as the input. where it gives the index of the word vector.

[image]

Comment: Sounds interesting but I don't think I understand what you want to do.  Examples will help a lot.

Comment: It is unclear, what you want to achieve? " use the embedding layer as one model and return the output vector " sounds like a standard embedding layer

Comment: @KotaMori updated.

Comment: @Digital-Thinking Updated.

Comment: still not clear to me, could you write in pseudo code to better explain?

Comment: take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer