# In Keras, CNN layer result is different from the result of model.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

```
history = model.fit(x_spectro_train, y_train_onehot, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=training_epochs, validation_data =(x_spectro_test, y_test_onehot), shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list,class_weight=class_weights, verbose=1)


model=load_model(model_name)
predict_prob_train = model.predict(x_spectro_train,batch_size=batch_size) 


inp = model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functors = [K.function([inp, K.learning_phase()], [out]) for out in outputs]    # evaluation functions
layer_outs = [func([x_spectro_train, 0.]) for func in functors] #test mode (0.0), train mode(1.0)
```

I want to save CNN layer outputs. 
I want to train the svm model with CNN layer outputs (not probability)

So I used code from [Keras, How to get the output of each layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer/41712013#41712013) and I saw the result.

But my result of CNN layer is different from the result of model.predict.
I monitored the val accuracy, save the best model, and load it.
This is structure of my model. (below image)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw71S.png)

I expected that result of layer_outs[13] (last layer) is same with predict_prob_train. However, the results were different. (like below image)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atpRo.png)

Why the results are different?

Answer (score 0):

You have 7 layers after `Conv` layer (2 of which are `Dense`). They also learn stuff and they are 'making the decision' of the model output.

Think about it like this: `Conv` outputs something, that is the input to `Dense1` -> `Dense2`. All those layers are learning simultaneously. So the goal of `Dense1` layer is to learn what `Conv` layer is 'trying to tell it', how to interpret the results of `Conv` layer. If you input the image to this `Dense1` layer and then to `Dense2` layer, you won't get the same result (nor correct one). All of those layers are working together to get the correct prediction.

You cannot isolate 1 layer and expect the correct result.

Comment: Thank you, then what is mean layer_outs? I think that these are all the results of each layer when all layers are being trained simultaneously. So I thought layers_out[13] was the result of passing the last dense layer when the model was trained at the same time using all layer. If not, what do the results mean?

Comment: Layer_out means the output of the model, output of the last layer of the model. That is what you have to interpret, that is the rezult

Comment: I mean that list name is 'layer_outs' with 13 elements. You can see it in my first picture. There are 13 Numpy array. I thought that Numpy array with index 13 in 'layer_outs' is output of the model when the model was trained using all layer. However, the result is different from model.predict.