# Get Cell, Input Gate, Output Gate and Forget Gate activation values for LSTM network using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I want to get the activation values for a given input of a trained LSTM network, specifically the values for the cell, the input gate, the output gate and the forget gate. According to this Keras [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/41) and this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer) I'm able to get some activation values with the following code:

(basically I'm trying to classify 1-dimensional timeseries using one label per timeseries, but that doesn't really matter for this general question)

```
import random
from pprint import pprint

import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import to_categorical

def getOutputLayer(layerNumber, model, X):
    return K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                      [model.layers[layerNumber].output])([X])

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 1), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

# generate some test data
for i in range(10):
    # generate a random timeseries of 100 numbers
    X = np.random.rand(10)
    X = X.reshape(10, 1, 1)

    # generate a random label for the whole timeseries between 0 and 1
    y = to_categorical([random.randint(0, 1)] * 10, num_classes=2)

    # train the lstm for this one timeseries
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
    model.reset_states()

# to keep the output simple use only 5 steps for the input of the timeseries
X_test = np.random.rand(5)
X_test = X_test.reshape(5, 1, 1)

# get the activations for the output lstm layer
pprint(getOutputLayer(0, model, X_test))
```

Using that I get the following activation values for the LSTM layer:

```
[array([[-0.04106992, -0.00327154, -0.01524276,  0.0055838 ,  0.00969929,
        -0.01438944,  0.00211149, -0.04286387, -0.01102304,  0.0113989 ],
       [-0.05771339, -0.00425535, -0.02032563,  0.00751972,  0.01377549,
        -0.02027745,  0.00268653, -0.06011265, -0.01602218,  0.01571197],
       [-0.03069103, -0.00267129, -0.01183739,  0.00434298,  0.00710012,
        -0.01082268,  0.00175544, -0.0318702 , -0.00820942,  0.00871707],
       [-0.02062054, -0.00209525, -0.00834482,  0.00310852,  0.0045242 ,
        -0.00741894,  0.00141046, -0.02104726, -0.0056723 ,  0.00611038],
       [-0.05246543, -0.0039417 , -0.01877101,  0.00691551,  0.01250046,
        -0.01839472,  0.00250443, -0.05472757, -0.01437504,  0.01434854]],
      dtype=float32)]
```

So I get for each input value 10 values, because I specified in the Keras model to use a LSTM with 10 neurons. But which one is a cell, which is is the input gate, which one the output gate, which one the forget gate?

Answer (score 0):

Well, these are the output values, to get and look into the value of each gate look into this [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1922)

I paste the essential part here

```
for i in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch', i, '/', epochs)
    model.fit(cos,
              expected_output,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              verbose=1,
              nb_epoch=1,
              shuffle=False)

    for layer in model.layers:
        if 'LSTM' in str(layer):
            print('states[0] = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.states[0])))
            print('states[1] = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.states[1])))

            print('Input')
            print('b_i = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.b_i)))
            print('W_i = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.W_i)))
            print('U_i = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.U_i)))

            print('Forget')
            print('b_f = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.b_f)))
            print('W_f = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.W_f)))
            print('U_f = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.U_f)))

            print('Cell')
            print('b_c = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.b_c)))
            print('W_c = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.W_c)))
            print('U_c = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.U_c)))

            print('Output')
            print('b_o = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.b_o)))
            print('W_o = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.W_o)))
            print('U_o = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.U_o)))

    # output of the first batch value of the batch after the first fit().
    first_batch_element = np.expand_dims(cos[0], axis=1)  # (1, 1) to (1, 1, 1)
    print('output = {}'.format(get_LSTM_output([first_batch_element])[0].flatten()))

    model.reset_states()

print('Predicting')
predicted_output = model.predict(cos, batch_size=batch_size)

print('Ploting Results')
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(expected_output)
plt.title('Expected')
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(predicted_output)
plt.title('Predicted')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get the error `AttributeError: 'LSTM' object has no attribute 'b_i'`

Comment: better if you make a new question with more details .e.g library version, and a sample code to reproduce

Comment: @Areza, can you please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77885671/how-to-get-the-output-of-each-gate-in-lstm-model-keras ?