# Accessing the gates of LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I would like to access the input to the gates of LSTM in Keras. Are there anyways available in Keras/Tensorflow to access the input/output of the gates of LSTM?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236656/get-cell-input-gate-output-gate-and-forget-gate-activation-values-for-lstm-net