# Is it possible to get 1st and 5th layer output from pretrained vgg model when predicting?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I need to use VGG pretrained model for feature extraction from an image. Also I need to get the output from the 1st and 5th layer of the VGG pretrained model. Is it really possible to do so?

**If yes, can anyone provide the working code?**

**Edit:**
I downloaded the pretrained model as

`model = VGG16()`

Then I predicted it with an image as:

`model.predict(image)`

Now I want to get the output of the intermediate layers(The 1st convolutional and 5th convolutional layer) as:

`x=model.layers[5].output`

but it yields a empty matrix when I convert the tensor. What is the problem in the code?

**N.B:** I need an output matrix not a tensor

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: Can you provide a code for the same.

Comment: I forgot how it was exactly. assign something like model.output and model.input to specific parts of your networks and then propagate data. But I'm sure this question is a duplicate

Comment: @BlueRineS  have edited the question according to my problem. I followed [keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer) but it is not the answer I need. I see they are not predicting from their model.

Comment: Actually I need a matrix not a tensor.

Comment: Maybe try the model.output code before you call predict() ?

Comment: It doesn't help either, produces output ```Tensor("block1_conv1/Relu:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 64), dtype=float32)``` I want the matrix as an output

Comment: Then convert the tensor to a numpy array. `from keras import backend as K; K.tf.get_value(tensor)`

Comment: It doesn't help either. You can test yourself.

Comment: what does it output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new model taking the layers you want.

```
newModel = Model(model.inputs, 
                 [model.layers[5].output, model.layers[i].output])
```

Predict from the new model:

```
layer5, layerI = newModel.predict(imageS)
```