# Create Features from a custom Keras CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been training this model for 1 epoch to see if it will work. What I want to do is take an image and create global features for the image. Right now after each training session, the features are all 0. Can someone please tell me the best way to create global features using Keras and cnn?

Here is my model so far.

```
def create_base_network():
    """
    Base network to be shared.
    """
    model_input = Input(shape=(224,224,3))

    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(model_input)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    #x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

    #x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.7)(x)

    x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.7)(x)

    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.7)(x)
    # This layer is what the features are
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)


    model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=x)
    return model
```

Please and thank you.

Comment: Oh the output is (x, 7,7,4096)

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean when you say "create global features"?

Comment: Like when you use Resnet50 without the last layer

Comment: resnet_model = resnet50.ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False)

Comment: Then feature = resnet_model.predict(img)

Comment: @MNM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer