# Value Error: No such layer - Extracting the output of a tensorflow keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to extract the output of `thelayer` in my autoencoder and have referenced [this](http://keras.io/getting-started/faq/) Keras documentation and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer) stackoverflow post so far. When I try to extract the output, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 36, in <module>
    outputs=autoencoder.get_layer(layer_name).output)
  File "..Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 36, in <module>
    outputs=autoencoder.get_layer(layer_name).output)
  File "..python3.6/site packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 567, in get_layer
    raise ValueError('No such layer: ' + name)
ValueError: No such layer: thelayer
", line 567, in get_layer
    raise ValueError('No such layer: ' + name)
ValueError: No such layer: thelayer
```

Code:

```
encoder_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(16,16,1), name="input")
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, 1, activation='relu',kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform)(encoder_img)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(1)(x)
inputtothelayer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 1, activation='relu')(x)
thelayer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(1)(inputtothelayer)

bottleneck = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu')(thelayer)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, 1, activation='relu')(bottleneck)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1024, 1, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(1)(x)
decoder_output = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation='relu')(x)
autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=encoder_img,outputs=decoder_output, name='autoencoder')
autoencoder.fit(data, data,
                epochs=1,
                batch_size=512,
                shuffle=True,)
layer_name = 'thelayer'
intermediate_layer_model = autoencoder(inputs=inputtothelayer, outputs=autoencoder.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
print(intermediate_layer_model)
```

Comment: The variable name is `thelayer` not the name of the layer.

Comment: @gorjan Why so? Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: Posted an answer. That solves the error you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following lines from:

```
thelayer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(1)(inputtothelayer)
bottleneck = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu')(thelayer)
```

to:

```
pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(1, name="thelayer")(inputtothelayer)
bottleneck = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu')(pool)
```

If you want to retrieve the layer by name `model.get_layer(layer_name)`, you should include the layer name in the `name` attribute. Furthermore, if you want to obtain the output from the intermediate layer, instead of doing:

```
layer_name = 'thelayer'
intermediate_layer_model = autoencoder(inputs=inputtothelayer, outputs=autoencoder.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
print(intermediate_layer_model)
```

Do the following:

```
layer_name = 'thelayer'
intermediate_layer_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=encoder_img, outputs=autoencoder.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(np.random.rand(10,16,16,1))
print(intermediate_layer_model)
```

Note that I am creating a new `tf.keras.Model` with the same `tf.keras.layers.Input`, where the output is the `intermediate_output`.

Comment: Gotcha, I need to specify a name for a layer next time. Thank you.

Comment: ```TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'outputs'``` hm I'm getting this error now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since I had changed the machine. it means the code was correct in the old machine but gave this error in the new machine.

solution>
I have installed>

```
pip install tf-nightly
```

and

```
pip install keras
```

Then it worked properly.