# Obtaining hidden layer outputs in a denoising autoencoder using Keras

Tags: keras, python-3.6, autoencoder, tensorflow2.0

I have built a `Sequential` Keras model with three layers: A `Gaussian Noise` layer, a hidden layer, and the output layer with the same dimension as the input layer.  For this, I'm using the **Keras** package that comes with **Tensorflow 2.0.0-beta1**.  Thus, I'd like to get the output of the hidden layer, such that I circumvent the `Gaussian Noise` layer since it's only necessary in the training phase.

To achieve my goal, I followed the instructions in https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer, which are pretty much described in [Keras, How to get the output of each layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer) too.

I have tried the following example from the official Keras documentation:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

dae = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.GaussianNoise( 0.001, input_shape=(10,) ),
    keras.layers.Dense( 80, name="hidden", activation="relu" ),
    keras.layers.Dense( 10 )
])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
dae.compile( loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["mae"] )

# Here the fitting process...
# dae.fit( · )

# Attempting to retrieve a decoder functor.
encoder = K.function([dae.input, K.learning_phase()], 
                               [dae.get_layer("hidden").output])
```

However, when `K.learning_phase()` is used to create the Keras backend functor, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 534, in _scratch_graph
    yield graph
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 3670, in __init__
    base_graph=source_graph)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/lift_to_graph.py", line 249, in lift_to_graph
    visited_ops = set([x.op for x in sources])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/lift_to_graph.py", line 249, in <listcomp>
    visited_ops = set([x.op for x in sources])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'op'
```

The code works great if I don't include `K.learning_phase()`, but I need to make sure that the output from my hidden layer is evaluated over an input that is not polluted with noise (i.e. in "test" mode -- not "training" mode).

I know my other option is to create a model from the original denoising autoencoder, but can anyone point me into why my approach from the officially documented functor creation fails?

Comment: It'd help if you shared your full model code - or its smallest version for a minimally-reproducible example. Also, if using `tensorflow.keras.backend`, make sure all your layers come from `tensorflow.keras`, rather than `keras`, for compatibility reasons

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I have added a simple code snippet that in my case fails when building the `encoder` functor.

Comment: Strange, no errors for me - are you packages up-to-date? Also, `encoder` won't get you the outputs - but I included a complete script in my answer that does. Let me know if it doesn't work. (Also, if not using already, I'd strongly recommend [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) for your python packages, as it ensures there are no conflicts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, ensure your packages are up-to-date, as your script works fine for me. Second, `encoder` won't get the outputs - continuing from your snippet after `# Here is the fitting process...`,

```py
x = np.random.randn(32, 10) # toy data
y = np.random.randn(32, 10) # toy labels
dae.fit(x, y) # run one iteration

encoder = K.function([dae.input, K.learning_phase()], [dae.get_layer("hidden").output])
outputs = [encoder([x, int(False)])][0][0] # [0][0] to index into nested list of len 1
print(outputs.shape)
# (32, 80)
```

However, as of **Tensorflow 2.0.0-rc2**, this will *not* work with eager execution enabled - disable via:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

Comment: Well, it's unfortunate, but this woks only for an environment with tensorflow 1.14 (stable release version).  I upgraded all of my packages via Anaconda, and I did not find a way to use `conda install` for **tensorflow 2.0.0-rc2**.  So, I had to use `pip install` for TF 2.

Comment: @YoungMin It's why I pass on betas, especially for something as massive as TF that's not nearly bug-free even out of beta. One way you can improve compatibility is, put your TF2 install where your TF1 was, in Anaconda folders - then run `conda update --all` - did this once myself, worked (but no promises; back up your working conda environment just in case). Lastly, try passing in `int(0)` instead of `K.learning_phase()`

Comment: @YoungMin Also, I just looked through the source code, and a relevant function was changed: `Function()`, which was used to evaluate `function()`; instead, it's now being imported from `tensorflow.python.keras.backend` as `tf_keras_backend`, and ultimately running via the`EagerExecutionFunction` class [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L3577), which _is_ pointed to by your error trace; it seems `int(0)` may actually be worse, as `.op` must evaluate to something valid

Comment: @YoungMin The _line numbers_, however, don't agree - and the link is from the master branch of TensorFlow. I'm unsure if rc2 is currently in master, but if it isn't, that's a strong reason to not use it yet -  but if it is, your package's not up to date

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  I upgraded TF from beta to RC2, so I have updated the traceback log in my original post.  I think I'll use the solution that involves creating a new model per the instructions given in the Keras webpage.  Moving from TF 1 to 2 will require them to greatly update their documentation online.

Comment: @YoungMin The lines are closer now, but still off - note that your line 3670 is master's [3652](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L3652). Now, did you try running it without eager? Eager won't make it any easier to see the outputs with the code you're using - and it may be the source of the bug. If disabling it doesn't work, open up [this file on this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/eager/lift_to_graph.py#L248) locally, and add `print(sources)` there - then rerun everything and see output

Comment: Yeah, it worked without eager execution!  Thanks @OverLordGoldDragon!