# Where are the activation values saved in tensorflow during model training?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, activation-function

In tensorflow2 ,we know that in backpropagation progress, we need weights and activations to calcute partial derivatives，I can find weights in stored in the model `tf.keras.Model`, but the activation values (intermediate values used for the calcualtions of back-propagation), where are they stored?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Gradients with Keras Tensorflow 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759635/get-gradients-with-keras-tensorflow-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

The activations are under `tf.keras.activations` check the [API docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations)

Comment: I suppose I do not clarify it clearly，I means that where do the activations result calculated in forward progress saved in tensorflow？

Comment: As I see it，in backpropagation progress，weight and activations result calculated in forward progress are intermediate factor to calculate partial of every weights，so they should be saved somewhere。

Comment: You can check the guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#intermediate_results) this part addresses the computation of intermediate gradients within Tensorflow, and If you are asking about accessing them during model training, then you will probably need to check on callbacks.

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759635/get-gradients-with-keras-tensorflow-2-0) I believe this is what you want.

Comment: You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58350527/how-to-get-activation-values-from-tensor-for-keras-model)