# Using Gradient Tape for Jacobian of LSTM model - Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradient, gradienttape

I am building a sequence to one model prediction using LSTM. My data has 4 input variables and 1 output variable which needs to be predicted. The data is a time series data. The total length of the data is 38265 (total number of timesteps). The total data is in a Data Frame of size 38265 *5

I want to use the previous 20 timesteps data of the 4 input variables to make prediction of my output variable. I am using the below code for this purpose.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units = 120, activation ='relu', return_sequences = False,input_shape = 
(train_in.shape[1],5)))
model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50,activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
```

I want to calculate the Jacobian of the output variable w.r.t the LSTM model function using tf.Gradient Tape .. Can anyone help me out with this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to segregate the Jacobian of the output with respect to the LSTM input can be done as follows:

1. Using [tf.GradientTape()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape), we can compute the Jacobian arising from the gradient flow.
2. However for getting the Jacobian , the input needs to be in the form of tf.EagerTensor which is usually available when we want to see the Jacobian of the output (after executing y=model(x)). The following code snippet shares this idea:

```py
#Get the Jacobian for each persistent gradient evaluation
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='relu'))
x = tf.constant([[5., 6., 3.]])

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True,watch_accessed_variables=True) as tape:
  # Forward pass
  tape.watch(x)
  y = model(x)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(y**2)
print('Gradients\n')
jacobian_wrt_loss=tape.jacobian(loss,x)
print(f'{jacobian_wrt_loss}\n')
jacobian_wrt_y=tape.jacobian(y,x)
print(f'{jacobian_wrt_y}\n')
```

3. But for getting intermediate outputs ,such as in this case, there have been many samples which use [Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer). When we separate the outputs coming out from model.layers.output, we get the type to be a Keras.Tensor instead of an EagerTensor.
   However for creating the Jacobian, we need the Eager Tensor. (After many failed attempts with @tf.function wrapping as eager execution is already present in TF>2.0)
4. So alternatively, an auxiliary model can be created with the layers required (in this case, just the Input and LSTM layers).The output of this model will be a tf.EagerTensor which will be useful for the Jacobian tensor creation. The following has been shown in this snippet:

```py
#General Syntax for getting jacobians for each layer output
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.executing_eagerly()
x=tf.constant([[15., 60., 32.]])
x_inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=tf.constant([[15., 60., 32.]]))
model=tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='relu',name='dense_1'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='relu',name='dense_2'))

aux_model=tf.keras.Sequential()
aux_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='relu',name='dense_1'))
#model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True,watch_accessed_variables=True) as tape:
  # Forward pass
  tape.watch(x)
  x_y = model(x)
  act_y=aux_model(x)
  print(x_y,type(x_y))
  ops=[layer.output for layer in model.layers]
    
# ops=[layer.output for layer in model.layers]
# inps=[layer.input for layer in model.layers]
print('Jacobian of Full FFNN\n')
jacobian=tape.jacobian(x_y,x)
print(f'{jacobian[0]}\n')

print('Jacobian of FFNN with Just first Dense\n')
jacobian=tape.jacobian(act_y,x)
print(f'{jacobian[0]}\n')
```

Here I have used a simple FFNN consisting of 2 Dense layers, but I want to evaluate w.r.t the output of the first Dense layer. Hence I created an auxiliary  model having just 1 Dense layer and determined the output of the Jacobian from it.

The details can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1m17doeyw7Tp8Eiqj-FVx0pAyr-UO7K1g?usp=sharing).

Comment: Hello @Abhilash Majumder , Thank you so much. It helped me understand and solve my issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

With the help from @Abhilash Majumder, I have done it this way. I am posting it here so that it might help someone in the future.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() #This will enable eager execution which is must.

```
tf.executing_eagerly() #check if eager execution is enabled or not. Should give "True"

data = pd.read_excel("FileName or Location ")
#My data is in the from of dataframe with 127549 rows and 5 columns(127549*5)

a = data[:20]  #shape is (20,5)
b = data[50:70] # shape is (20,5)
A = [a,b]  # making a list
A = np.array(A) # convert into array size (2,20,5) 

At = tf.convert_to_tensor(A, np.float32) #convert into tensor
At.shape # TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(20), Dimension(5)])

model = load_model('EKF-LSTM-1.h5') # Load the trained model
# I have a trained model which is shown in the question above. 
# Output of this model is a single value

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True,watch_accessed_variables=True) as tape:

tape.watch(At)
y1 = model(At) #defining your output as a function of input variables
print(y1,type(y1)

#output 
tf.Tensor([[0.04251503],[0.04634088]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32) <class 
'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>

jacobian=tape.jacobian(y1,At) #jacobian of output w.r.t both inputs
jacobian.shape
```

## Outupt

```
TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(1), Dimension(2), Dimension(20), Dimension(5)])
```

Here I calculated Jacobian w.r.t 2 inputs each of size (20,5). If you want to calculate w.r.t to only one input of size (20,5), then use this

```
jacobian=tape.jacobian(y1,At[0]) #jacobian of output w.r.t only 1st input in 'At'
jacobian.shape
```

## Output

```
TensorShape([Dimension(1), Dimension(1), Dimension(1), Dimension(20), Dimension(5)])
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to compute the Jacobian over a series of inputs and outputs that are independent of each other for `input[i]`, `output[j]`, `i != j`, consider the `batch_jacobian` method.

This will reduce the number of dimensions in your computed Jacobian tensor by one and could be the difference between running out of memory and not.

See: `batch_jacobian` in the [TensorFlow GradientTape docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape).