# How to print the dense layer values?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have created a CNN model. In that I want to the print 1D array values of the dense layer. How can I print the dense layer output vector in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras, How to get the output of each layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer)

Answer (score 0):

Please check:
[Keras, How to get the output of each layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer)

When creating your dense layer you can use "name" argument, like:

```
model.add(Dense(1024, name="my_dense_layer"))
```

Than you get this layer output using:

```
model.get_layer("my_dense_layer").output
```

For example, assume you have trained model 'model' and want to get outputs of a layer with name 'hidden1' on input data 'x_test'. You can do:

```
from keras.models import Model
layer_name = 'my_dense_layer'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,  
    outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: it's not printing the values.
I want to see the array values 
it's printing: <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 21) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'DenseLayer')>
so, how can i print the value

Comment: I have extended my answer above. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: i want to see the "matching score" of the network.
so, how can i print the score from it